# Simply-fy my less using LESS functions

Tags: css, less

I would like to make the following code more maintainable (but less understandable is okay) by creating some sort of looping function that would create the CSS code using my LESS parser;

```
.box {
        &.ebay {
            background-color:@ebay-color;
            h2, p{
                color: lighten(@ebay-color, 15%);
            }
        }
        &.google-shopping {
            background-color:@google-shopping-color;
            h2, p{
                color: lighten(@google-shopping-color, 15%);
            }
        }
        &.website {
            background-color:@website-color;
            h2, p{
                color: lighten(@website-color, 15%);
            }
        }
        &.feed {
            background-color: @feed-color;
            h2, p{
                color: lighten(@feed-color, 15%);
            }
        }
        &.twitter {
            background-color: @twitter-color;
            h2, p{
                color: lighten(@twitter-color, 15%);
            }
        }
        &.facebook {
            background-color:@facebook-color;
            h2, p{
                color: lighten(@facebook-color, 15%);
            }
        }
    }
```

So wouldn't it be great if I had a function that would A) loop over all the colors (ebay,google-shopping etc) and then another function that would output the style with the right colors.

**Question**

Is there a way to store my colours in an array and have a function that accepted the style for one of the above 6 blocks and then produced the same style (with the parameter for the color) in each block? and, what is this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is a Bug that Prevents the Perfect Approach

This is using LESS 1.4+. The following achieves it, but the `lighten()` has to be predone because of a bug currently in LESS (see explanation following solution).

**LESS**

```css
@numAssociations: 6;
@Associations: ebay google-shopping website feed twitter facebook;
@ebay-color: #ff0000;
@ebay-color-contrast: lighten(@ebay-color, 15%);
@google-shopping-color: #0000ff;
@google-shopping-color-contrast: lighten(@google-shopping-color, 15%);
@website-color: #ffff00;
@website-color-contrast: lighten(@website-color, 15%);
@feed-color: #ffffff;
@feed-color-contrast: lighten(@feed-color, 15%);
@twitter-color: #ffc0cb;
@twitter-color-contrast: lighten(@twitter-color, 15%);
@facebook-color: #ffa500;
@facebook-color-contrast: lighten(@facebook-color, 15%);

//loop code
.buildClassColorAssociations(@i) when (@i =< @numAssociations) {
  @className: extract(@Associations, @i);
  @bkgColor:  ~'@{@{className}-color}';
  @color:  ~'@{@{className}-color-contrast}';
  &.@{className} {
    background-color: @bkgColor;
    h2, p {
      color: @color;
    }
  }
  .buildClassColorAssociations(@i + 1);
}
//end the loop
.buildClassColorAssociations(@i) when (@i = (@numAssociations + 1)) {}
//call the loop
.buildClassColorAssociations(1);
```

**CSS Output**

```css
.ebay {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.ebay h2,
.ebay p {
  color: #ff4d4d;
}
.google-shopping {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
.google-shopping h2,
.google-shopping p {
  color: #4d4dff;
}
.website {
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
.website h2,
.website p {
  color: #ffff4d;
}
.feed {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.feed h2,
.feed p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.twitter {
  background-color: #ffc0cb;
}
.twitter h2,
.twitter p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.facebook {
  background-color: #ffa500;
}
.facebook h2,
.facebook p {
  color: #ffc04d;
}
```

This can, of course, be nested inside any class, so just call the mixin from within

```
.box { .buildClassColorAssociations(1); }
```

to get your original, desired output for that class.

### BUG EXPLANATION:

Ideally, the code would be something like this:

**LESS**

```css
@numAssociations: 6;
@Associations: ebay google-shopping website feed twitter facebook;
@ebay-color: #ff0000;
@google-shopping-color: #0000ff;
@website-color: #ffff00;
@feed-color: #ffffff;
@twitter-color: #ffc0cb;
@facebook-color: #ffa500;

//loop code
.buildClassColorAssociations(@i) when (@i =< @numAssociations) {
  @className: extract(@Associations, @i);
  @color:  color(~'@{@{className}-color}'); //<-- color conversion fails, yet is
                                               needed for lighten() to work so...
  &.@{className} {
    background-color: @color;
    h2, p {
      color: lighten(@color,15%); //<-- ... lighten fails, making a compile error
    }
  }
  .buildClassColorAssociations(@i + 1);
}
//end the loop
.buildClassColorAssociations(@i) when (@i = (@numAssociations + 1)) {}
//call the loop
.buildClassColorAssociations(1);
```

**BUT, the CSS Output shows that LESS is not handling the color conversion
properly, so the `lighten()` function fails (it makes a compile error), because the `@color` is producing this CSS output:**

```css
.ebay {
  background-color: #NaNeebbaaNaNNaNccNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN;
}
.ebay h2,
.ebay p {
  /* color: lighten(@color,15%); yields an error */

}
.google-shopping {
  background-color: #NaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNeeNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNccNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN;
}
.google-shopping h2,
.google-shopping p {
  /* color: lighten(@color,15%); yields an error */

}
.website {
  background-color: #NaNNaNeebbNaNNaNNaNeeNaNccNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN;
}
.website h2,
.website p {
  /* color: lighten(@color,15%); yields an error */

}
.feed {
  background-color: #NaNffeeeeddNaNccNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN;
}
.feed h2,
.feed p {
  /* color: lighten(@color,15%); yields an error */

}
.twitter {
  background-color: #NaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNeeNaNNaNccNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN;
}
.twitter h2,
.twitter p {
  /* color: lighten(@color,15%); yields an error */

}
.facebook {
  background-color: #NaNffaacceebbNaNNaNNaNNaNccNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN;
}
.facebook h2,
.facebook p {
  /* color: lighten(@color,15%); yields an error */

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could just do this:

```
.fn(@color) {
    background-color: @color;
    h2, p{
        color: lighten(@color, 15%);
    }
}

.box {
    &.ebay {
        .fn(@ebay-color);
    }
    &.google-shopping {
        .fn(@google-shopping-color);
    }
    &.website {
        .fn(@website-color);
    }
    &.feed {
        .fn(@feed-color);
    }
    &.twitter {
        .fn(@twitter-color);
    }
    &.facebook {
        .fn(@facebook-color);
    }
}
```

Change .fn to whatever you want.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this solution is what you need. You can't do for loops very well in LESS and you can't use arrays either.

Comment: Yeh fair enough, I actually did that already and I was keen to take it to the next level. You can actually loop in less: http://blog.thehippo.de/2012/04/programming/do-a-loop-with-less-css/

Comment: And for an array, I was imagining that you can do a function that you pass a number too (1,2,3,4,5) and it will return the color string. Unsure if that's possible

Comment: BTW... I like your answer, it does get us halfway there! I killed it off before because I was trying to pass through the actual css inside the function as a parameter too. This way is still good.

Comment: Notice I said loops very well. ;)